# Print only html table using javascript

Tags: java, html, printing

I have the following basic html table with a Java function to print only the table content However the Print button does nothing when clicked,I figure probably the java coding is the issue, however it is not working could I get a third pair of eyes to assist please

```
<html>
<body>

<table border="1" cellpadding="3" id="printTable">
    <tbody><tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>      
        <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>      
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>        
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>        
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>        
        <td>67</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>

<br />
<br />

<button>Print me</button>

<script>
function printData()
{
   var divToPrint=document.getElementById("printTable");
   newWin= window.open("");
   newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
   newWin.print();
   newWin.close();
}

$('button').on('click',function(){
printData();
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the issue you're having?

Comment: @Paco the print button does nothing when I run the code

Comment: Do you understand the code you posted? If so, you should edit your post explaining exactly what it is supposed to do. What do you expect to happen? and so on

Comment: @Paco Yes The table has an ID="printTable" which refers to the java function "PrintData", and when the button is clicked it shoud print only the table with the PrintTable Id, however Nothiong happens when the button is clicked, and thats what I am seeking help with

Comment: Remove outerHtml & instead try `document.getElementById("printable").innerHTML`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to the javascript function is not correct. When you're using the '$' symbol it means that you're using JQuery. You have 2 options:

1 - Include the jquery library to your page:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

2 - Call the javascript function directly on the button on the 'onclick' event. This is the best option in your case:

```
<button onclick="printData()">Print me</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

When working with javascript, it is often useful to look at your browser's console. After opening this page, mine has the error:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

`$` is a global variable inserted by jQuery. Try adding

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to the code. This will include the jQuery library.

Comment: Be sure to add it before $ is used - right after `<button>Print me</button>` would be a good place.

Answer (score 1):

```
Change this var divToPrint=document.getElementById("printTable");
to this var divToPrint=document.getElementById("<%=printTable.ClientID>");

and add jquery library <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```